# Make the phone always-listening to "OK Google" with fingerprint sensor on Nexus 5X

Tags: smart-lock, ok-google, nexus-5x, fingerprint

I have a Nexus 5X running Android 6 Marshmallow, and I want "OK Google" trained to my voice to work when the device is on but the screen is off. I also use fingerprint scanner for "smart lock"/screen lock. When I say "OK Google", the device requests a fingerprint or PIN before it will do the action requested. This renders the feature pretty useless as it's mostly a hands-free tool. (Note: "OK Google" works perfectly with no screen lock activated.)

Given that OK Google is trained to my voice only and that it is a hands-free feature, I find it strange that I can't use it that way when using the fingerprint scanner or other screen lock feature. Is there a way to do it?

I'm happy to have no screen lock but just have the fingerprint scanner turn the screen on instead, if that's possible - I find it useful when taking the device out of my pocket.

Comment: Can you check the setting if the "Trusted voice" is enabled on **Google Settings - Voice -  "Ok Google" detection - Trusted voice**?

Comment: Yes its enabled and trained to my voice

Answer (score 2):

Under **Security** and under **Smart Lock**, go to **Trusted voice** and check the option that says **Always on**. That's how I got "OK Google" to work when my phone is locked. I use the fingerprint lock as well.

Comment: Nope, still asks for pin/pattern, even with these settings